# How to extract particular text after specific pattern in string

Tags: bash

I have some Bash code where am planning to extract the ID from string. I have tried my code to find the ID after pattern "ID:". It is extracting the ID value but after that it is taking remaining text after ID. I want to extract only ID in that line and not the remaining text.

I have tried below code

```
$ string="ID: 2454-45-343-345 this is generated ID"
$ output="${string#*ID: }"
$ echo $output
```

output

```
2454-45-343-345 this is generated ID
```

am expecting output should only be `2454-45-343-345` and not remaining text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way of doing it. Assuming that you have only one ID in a line which is matching with the ID pattern:

```
string="ID: 2454-45-343-345 this is generated ID"
output="${string//[!0-9+-]/}"
echo $output
```

Answer (score 2):

You could in a second step just remove the unwanted tail from `output`:

```
 output="${string#*ID: }"
 output=${output%% *}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you are ok with an `awk` solution try.

```
echo "$string" | awk 'match($0,/[0-9]+\-[0-9+\-[0-9]+\-[0-9]+/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}'
```

Comment: @mandar joshi, could you please do let me know if this had worked for you?